# automake Environment Variable Condition

Tags: makefile, conditional-statements, environment-variables, autotools, automake

I have a file Makefile.am I am using to generate a Makefile. In the generated Makefile I want to have something like:

```
ifndef SOURCECODEPATH
   SOURCECODEPATH := /home/root/source_code_path
endif
```

It seems so simple, does anyone know how I can do it?

Answer (score 6):

Use the [AM_CONDITIONAL](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Usage-of-Conditionals.html) macro in `configure.ac`.

The script sets a variable you can test, e.g., a variable that is set to non-empty if the condition is enabled: `AM_CONDITIONAL([ENABLE_SOURCECODEPATH], [test "x$ac_srcpath" != "x"])`

Then in `Makefile.am`:

```
if !ENABLE_SOURCECODEPATH
SOURCECODEPATH = ...
endif
```

However, since you are explicitly defining the variable if it's not defined, you should probably define it in `configure.ac` regardless, using `AC_SUBST(SRCPATH, $ac_srcpath)` :

```
SOURCECODEPATH = @SRCPATH@ # or $(SRCPATH)
```

Comment: There's not a way to just tell automake to copy the text from Makefile.am into the Makefile?

Answer (score 4):

you could simply use an auxiliary makefile that get's included by Makefile.am (and it's expansion).

Makefile.am:

```
#...
include Makefile.env
#...
```

and Makefile.env:

```
ifndef SOURCECODEPATH
   SOURCECODEPATH := /home/root/source_code_path
endif
```

`automake` will not touch (or try to parse) the `include`d Makefile.env

Comment: Didn't test but make sense and seems like the best solution. Hate the idea of using 2 files for something so simple. Hoping to try to break away from autotools for building a 10 file or so GStreamer plugin. This is my first experience with autotools but seems like it's not good for code maintainability and an easy to use build system.

Comment: i think the point of autotools is to provide a cross-platform maintainable and easy to use build system. and it does so quite well. unfortunately it is not an *easy to learn* build system, and requires that you adapt their way of thinking rather than trying to enforce your own ways; i'm sure autotools has already a nice, easy solution to the problem you initially wanted to solve with your construct (which of course is unclear from the snippet you provided)

Answer (score 0):

The following solution should work in at least GNU Make and BSD Make. The [autotools solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14553976/1257631) by Brett Hale should work everywhere, but it's considerably more complex.

```
SOURCECODEPATH?=/home/root/source_code_path
```

Comment: That almost worked... I had to add a space before the ? and after the = for automake to process it (SOURCECODEPATH ?= /home/root/source_code_path). It copied the SOURCECODEPATH assignment to the bottom of the Makefile verbatim, but it would not compile. I moved the SOURCECODEPATH assignment to the top of the Makefile and it compiled. Any way to automatically move it to the top of the Makefile? I have SOURCECODEPATH ?=... as the first line in Makefile.am.

Comment: Unfortunately, my expertise is with `make` only, and not with the `autotools` suite.

Comment: Alas i can't insert code block in comment, so i posted answer as a comment, see below.

Answer (score 0):

You really should not be using automake to generate non-portable makefiles, but if you really want to do this to generate a Makefile for use with GNU make then you can simply add a space before the `endif`:

```
ifndef SOURCECODEPATH
   SOURCECODEPATH := /home/root/source_code_path
 endif
```

If the `e` is not in the first column, Automake will not try to parse `endif` as the end of an automake conditional, but will copy the text verbatim to the Makefile.  GNU-make will recognize the conditional with the space (at least, 3.80 recognizes it.  I haven't tried any others.)

Comment: It didn't copy the text verbatim for me. It actually just copied the SOURCECODEPATH := ... line verbatim, regardless of if SOURCECODEPATH was defined or not. (Make v3.81, automake v1.11.3)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, as http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors says, `?=` is used for variables declared with `=`. If you need set default values for variables declared with `:=`, use construction like this:

```
ifeq ($(origin SOURCECODEPATH), undefined)
  SOURCECODEPATH := /home/root/source_code_path
endif
```