# Automake: Change targets according to environment variable

Tags: testing, makefile, environment-variables, autotools, automake

I want to be able to change the `TESTS` according to an environment variable like this

```
make check EXTRA=more
```

The makefile is generated with Automake. I don't want a configure-time solution via [AM_CONDITIONAL](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Usage-of-Conditionals.html). I also don't want to use `make check TESTS=more` since per default the test shouldn't be in `TESTS`.

The background is that there are tests that take a long time and shouldn't be run with a normal `make check`. Adding another target like `make extracheck` can be done but this doesn't give me the convenient [parallel test harness](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Parallel-Test-Harness.html) from automake. If there is some variable in automake like `TESTS_MORE` that automagically works, I would love to hear it.

It should be possible to do it in plain `make` in a portable way. Someone mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14553389/automake-environment-variable-condition) that automake would not touch a Makefile that I `include` but this is not what I observe. Also the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Include.html) says that included files are interpreted by `automake` and not `make`.

If it isn't possible via environment variables, maybe you have a good alternative solution?

Comment: What's that bit about the parallel test harness?

Comment: I added a link. It is just the nice usual live-updating summary that you get when you `make check`.

Comment: Can you explain the aversion to `make check TESTS=more`? You mean you wan to *add* tests to the default set with your `EXTRA` variable and `TESTS` normally contains the correct default tests?

Comment: Exactly: `make check` should do the default set in `TESTS` without the long running ones. AFAIK `make check TESTS=more` can only select from the given tests. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I don't know whether you can select a test that isn't in the default set like that or not. I would think you could as long as the (auto)make stuff knows how to run the tests (I'm not sure what you have to do to make it know how to do that). You could always manually remove the long-running tests *in* the makefile and then manually add everything in `EXTRA` back to `TESTS` if you do need to work around that limitation.

Comment: If you *don't* need the long tests in `TESTS` by default for this to work then an alternate target or the original idea should work just fine I think.

Comment: did you try to add EXTRA to TESTS? TESTS+=$(EXTRA)  If EXTRA is not defined this is a NOP. otherwise your longrunning tests are run